# Jenkins not passing "Properties" to maven while building

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

[image]

I configured Jenkins to build a maven project. While building, I pass the Properties in the "Properties" section as mentioned in the image. when I trigger the build, I would see: `mvn -f test/pom.xml -Dname1=value1 -Dname2=value2 clean test`

This above setup was working perfectly.

However, all of a sudden the setup stopped working. The way maven is building currently is:  `mvn -f test/pom.xml clean test`

I noticed that properties were not passed to maven

The only thing that I did was installing "Job Configuration History" and "Configuration Slicing" plugins. I tried editing "Maven Top Level Targets" inside "Configuration Slicing" and that perhaps disrupted things. I uninstalled
both "Job Configuration History" and "Configuration Slicing" plugins. But I still see the problem

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved. I had to enable the "Inject build variables" under "Invoke top-level Maven targets"

Comment: Interestingly, the comment for this checkbox says that one should not use it, but pass  properties (especially build variables) explicitly. So I think this might be a bug...
_"Pass all build variables into maven process in form of java properties. This is seldom needed as Jenkins provides it as environment variables anyway. Preferred way to access Jenkins build variables is to explicitly map it to property in Properties section (MY_VAR=${MY_VAR})."_